# A procedure to install minishift on Fedora?

Tags: redhat-containers

This nice article describe very well how to install minishift on Windows, MacOS and RHEL:
[Hello World!](https://developers.redhat.com/products/cdk/hello-world/#fndtn-rhel)

Unfortunately, there is no procedure for Fedora, can you provide some guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to download the CDK (minishift) binary directly from [download](https://developers.redhat.com/products/cdk/download/) page. You just need to be registered.

Next, you should configure your system environment (ie. set up hypervisor driver), take a look [here](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/getting-started/setting-up-virtualization-environment.html).

Make the downloaded CDK binary executable:

```
chmod +x cdk-x.y.z-minishift-linux-amd64
```

Finally, you can continue with setting up the cdk binary as described in section 2 in [Hello World](https://developers.redhat.com/products/cdk/hello-world/#fndtn-rhel) page. Mainly, this is about preparing minishift configuration for proper hypervisor (as user can use more than one):

```
./cdk-x.y.z-minishift-linux-amd64 setup-cdk
```

or

```
./cdk-x.y.z-minishift-linux-amd64 setup-cdk --default-vm-driver xxx
```

in case that you are using different than default hypervisor (kvm on linux, could be virtualbox).